# Update Mongo on the client using document ID, but limiting search with another field

Tags: meteor

When updating a document which contains an array of objects, I have this function:

```
Template.editCompetition.events = {
'click button.promote': function() {
        Competitions.update({_id: Session.get('competition_id'), 'players.user_id': this.user_id}, {$set: {'players.$.supervisor': true}});
    },
};
```

I am seeing the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID.
```

My document looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 'aaaabbbbb',
    title: 'ccccdddddd',
    players: [
        {
            username: 'wwwww',
            user_id: 'xxxxx',
            supervisor: false
        },
        {
            username: 'yyyyy',
            user_id: 'zzzzz',
            supervisor: false
        }]
}
```

Isn't my query updating the document by the ID, but also searching for that array position to use the .$ notation.

How can I achieve this without using a method, which seems a bit hacky...?

Answer (score 0):

You are also trying to use the `player.user_id` as second parameter for `update` query

Other option you can have to use `Meteor.method`.

Move Collection update code to Meteor server side method and call it from client side

On Server side,

```
Meteor.methods({

   `update_players`: function(competition_id){
     user_id = this.userId
     Competitions.update({_id: competition_id, 'players.user_id': user_id}, {$set: {'players.$.supervisor': true}});
   }
})
```

In in above code, understand use of how we fetched current userId with `this.userId`

and now from your click handler call this meteror method

```
Meteor.call('update_players')
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks ajduke, I already have it working right now as a Method, but I am trying to move methods back into local (client) db activities.

Comment: @cstrat ok, my bad. didn't properly read your last line of your question. I thought it like _using this method_, which you are using currently. Anyways, why using methods is hacky ?

Comment: It just seems hacky because I don't understand the error and I am working around it... The error seems to indicate that you can only update via an ID - and that is what is happening here, but I am also searching within that doc.